# Difference between 防衛相, 防衛大臣 and 国防相

Tags: usage, nuances, definitions

Reading a NHK NEWS article, I stumbled over three different expressions for *minister of defence*. Is there a difference between 防衛相, 防衛大臣 and 国防相?

Comment: No difference between 防衛相 and 防衛大臣 for me. you can find the definition of 防衛相 on [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%98%B2%E8%A1%9B%E5%A4%A7%E8%87%A3). 

*2007年（平成19年）1月の防衛庁から防衛省への昇格に伴い、長の職名は長官から大臣になった。略称は防衛相である*

And [国防省](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%98%B2%E8%A1%9B%E7%9C%81)

*日本では防衛省だが、英語での名称は他国の国防省と同じである*

Comment: Also the pronunciation of 防衛相 (the minister) and 防衛省 (the ministry) is the same so using 防衛大臣  helps eliminate misunderstanding. Same for 財務大臣・財務相・財務省 and 外務大臣・外務相・外務省 etc.

~大臣 is the formal name from a legal standpoint meaning that in laws and ordinances ~相 isn't used.